# Why does command line mongodb fail on mongorestore?

Tags: mongodb, out-of-memory, mongorestore

I have started mongodb instance:

```
nohup mongod --dbpath /var/data/instance1  --port 27001 --bind_ip <ip> &> instance1.out&
```

also I have tried this, it does not help:

```
nohup mongod --dbpath /var/data/instance1  --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 1 --port 27001 --bind_ip <ip> &> instance1.out&
```

After this I have started mongorestore:

```
nohup mongorestore  -d <db> --noIndexRestore  /var/dump/<db>&
```

Later OOM killer kills mongodb instance during restore. After that a half of RAM becomes cached:

```
free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         28415      28267        147          0         26      14423
-/+ buffers/cache:      13818      14597
Swap:         8326         31       8295
```

My OS is debian 3.2,  mongodb version is 3.4.7 .

P.S.:  Mongorestore works fine if I started mongodb with

```
/etc/init.d/mongod start
```

Comment: try this https://serverfault.com/questions/537176/mongodb-getting-oom-killed

Answer (score 0):

1  to  /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory   solves the problem (was 0).